# Flutter-why uuid change after uninstall and install apps in ios

Tags: flutter, dart, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I am using [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package of flutter to get uuid of a phone, but every time I do uninstall apps and then install it again the uuid changes. it happens in ios device

Is there a way to get uniq id of a phone?

Here is part of the code when I am using [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) to get uuid user

```
_readIosDeviceInfoRegis(IosDeviceInfo data) =>
      data.identifierForVendor.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issue on the plugin. You can check the link below for more information.

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/447

As an alternative, you can actually use [flutter_udid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_udid) package. This will create consistent uuids.

```
import 'package:flutter_udid/flutter_udid.dart';
String udid = await FlutterUdid.consistentUdid;
```

Comment: I take a look at the link you have given and adding a comment there. And I still have the same question, so right now I am trying your solution by using flutter_udid to get uniq id for ios device. I have tried it in one of simulator and there is no problem when I do uninstall my apps and then do reinstall... the id will keep static like what you said. I haven't try it in another simulator. So, I would like to ask you.. so far when you use flutter_udid package to get uniq id, is there any other problem that you get ?